# onchange event handler failing to call function

Tags: javascript, dynamic, event-handling

I have a function that uses:

```
name = "textBox" + (h) + (j);
id = "textBox" + (h) + (j);
value = hoursEachDay[j-1];
textBox = "<input type='text' maxlength='6' size='6' name='" + name + "'id='"+ id +"' value='" + value + "' onchange='updateHrs()'>";//or parent.updateHrs(j)
```

(h, i,and j being integers) to call another function that follows *directly* after the first function. That function is :

```
function updateHrs()// or updateHrs(dayOfMonth)
{
    alert("This is the day changed ");
    //or alert("This is the day changed " + dayOfMonth);
    return;
}
```

I get a 'function not defined' error from firebug when I run this and trigger the onchange event handler. I have, on the suggestion of a coworker, changed updateHrs() to parent.updateHrs(), which actually works for some reason, until I try to pass a variable into the updateHrs() function (ass seen commented out above), at which point it declares that updateHrs(j) is not defined.

I am guessing that somehow the updateHrs function is being read as out of scope, although I'm not really sure how. Both of these functions are right after one another and both are right before the  tag (yes there is a  tag well above them as well), so they should not have a scope issue, not that I'm aware of anyway.

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Comment: Is `updateHrs()` declared as a global function? Also if you're creating these fields in a loop then to pass the correct `j` value to the function it would need to be `"' onchange='updateHrs(" + j + ")'>"`. (Putting the actual value directly in the output html, otherwise every field would try to refer to the same global `j` variable.)

Comment: @nnnnnn, you should post this as an answer

Comment: @MaciejŁebkowski - Well it's not an answer. Either way it doesn't explain why the function is undefined.

Comment: @nnnnnn it’s probably inside an iframe. hard to tell without the whole code

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the issue. Doh! And yes, it was in an iframe. I will have to think about why it didn't call, as I would think it would, even with that error.

Comment: Weird. If my suggestion about `j` fixed it then I wouldn't expect "function not defined" from your original code, I'd expect some sort of reference error about `j`. Though yes, if the fields are being added to an iframe but the function is in the parent you would definitely need `parent.updateHrs()`.